# Crontab Certain Days of Week Colliding

Tags: linux, cron, centos6

I've setup a backup rotation on a centos 6 crontab, one script should run Mon-Sat, the other on a Sunday, never on the 1st of the month.  However the weekly (Sunday only) script has been running every night, and the daily ran on Sunday.  Confirmed by the cron.log

```
#Daily - Midnight, Mon-Sat, Not on the 1st of the Month
0 0 2-31 * 1-6 script_daily

#Weekly - Midnight, Sunday, Not on the 1st of the Month
0 0 2-31 * 0 script_weekly
```

I can't work out what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've pulled relevant lines from the cron log.  The 28th was a Sunday.

```
Jun 28 00:00:01 backup CROND[2000]: (root) CMD (script_daily)
Jun 28 00:00:01 backup CROND[2004]: (root) CMD (script_weekly)
Jun 29 00:00:01 backup CROND[9438]: (root) CMD (script_daily)
Jun 29 00:00:01 backup CROND[9443]: (root) CMD (script_weekly)
Jun 30 00:00:02 backup CROND[6893]: (root) CMD (script_daily)
Jun 30 00:00:02 backup CROND[6898]: (root) CMD (script_weekly)
```

Comment: The only question I would have for you is -- when you say "Midnight", are you thinking about "that night" or "that morning"?  For a computer "Monday at midnight" is right after "Sunday at 11:59pm".  Is that perhaps the source of your confusion?

Comment: I understand how this could add confusion, perhaps the comment should say 'Early Morning' - to clear up confusion i've added the relevant output from the cron log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man page

```
If you  spec-
ify  both  a day in the month and a day of week, it will be interpreted
as the Nth such day in the month.
```

[...]

```
To request the last Monday, etc.  in a month, ask for  the  "5th"  one.
This  will  always  match the last Monday, etc., even if there are only
four Mondays in the month:


     # run at 11 am on the first and last Mon, Tue, Wed of each month
     0 11 1,5 * mon-wed date

When the fourth Monday in a month is the last, it  will  match  against
both  the "4th" and the "5th" (it will only run once if both are speci-
fied).
```

In short...

```
0 0 2-31 * 1-6 script_daily
```

Second through last monday/tuesday/wednesday/thursday/friday/saturday of each month

```
0 0 2-31 * 0 script_weekly
```

Second through last sunday of each month

Off the top of my head, I suspect the correct answer is "teach your scripts to exit immediately if they see they are running on the 1st of the month" and then run your jobs as

```
0 0 * * 1-6 script_daily
0 0 * * 0 script_weekly
```